# ORDER BY and LIMIT 2 different parameters

Tags: mysql, limit

I have a table `events` which contains `timestamp`.
I want to `SELECT`two events the next events coming out and the last 8 events in the past.
With  two different queries it would be:
1)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp > timeNow ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 0,2
```

2)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp < timeNow ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 0,8
```

Is it possible to do only one query?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried a UNION between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [UNION or UNION ALL](http://mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp > timeNow ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM events WHERE timestamp < timeNow ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 8;
```

Also, remember `LIMIT 8` is equivalent to `LIMIT 0, 8`. The reason for this is that `LIMIT 0, 8` means "start at row 0 and restrict the number of rows returned to 8"

Comment: What is the meaning of LIMIT 0,2. Can't we simply write LIMIT 2; ?

Comment: yes you can write LIMIT 2 instead of LIMIT 0,2. They are functionally identical! I've amended my answer a little to describe this.